# WindowsformsHost in Windows Universal App

Tags: c#, wpf, universal, windowsformshost

Is it possible to host a Windows Forms container (so called WindowsFormsHost) in a windows Universal App? I tried this in VisualStudio and VS tells me that Windows Forms Host is not available, "perhaps you are missing an assembly?"

So I know that WindowsFormsHost is available in "normal" WPF projects - but is it available in an Universal Application as well?

Comment: WinForms doesn't really sound like an universal app component. And no, it's not available as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185501.aspx

Comment: Pretty sad but understandable from the point of view of Microsoft.
I will switch to WPF application instead.

This question is solved and can be closed. Thank you for your help.